# Best way to plot Points on Map using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working to plot points of a huge data set in map .
Something like : http://bikes.oobrien.com/chicago/

```
[
{
"event":'share',
"lat":41.92866814708094,
"long":-87.70242605646864},
{
"event":'rapheal',
"lat":34.03,
"long":23.01},
{
"event":'share',
"lat":41.92866814708094,
"long":-87.70242605646864},
..
]
```

Can I do that using D3.JS ?
I found cool stuffs here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/
Or should I use cartodb.com to build that.

Comment: Yes, you can do that using D3.

Comment: Lars Kotthoff Can you recommend tutorials/blogs

Comment: There is for example [this one](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/), which should be reasonably easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, D3 is well-suited to this. There is in-built latitude/longitude projection https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections so you need to think about what suits your dataset best.

However, D3 is a drawing tool and not a mapping tool. You'll need to source map coordinates as GEO JSON to plot the outlines of wherever you're looking at, and it will take a lot of work to build up a map as detailed as Ollie's bike maps. You'll get a lot of power with D3, but it might be more work than CartoDB.